# Generate dynamically URL in python

Tags: python, url, urllib

I would like to programatically generate a URL made by these parts

Fixed part

```
https://booking.snav.it/#/booking/rates/
```

Outbound route number - changes

```
1040
```

Outbound date - changes

```
19-02-2019
```

Inbound route number - changes

```
1042
```

Inbound date - changes

```
20-02-2019
```

Parameters:

```
"adults": "1"
"childs":"0"
"infants":"0"
"res": "0"
"vehicle":"0"
```

Output

```
https://booking.snav.it/#/booking/rates/1040/19-02-2019/1042/19-02-2019?adults=1&childs=0&infants=0&res=0&vehicle=0
```

I know how to pass parameters with `urllib.parse.urlencode`

```
params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
   "adults": "1"
    "childs":"0"
    "infants":"0"
    "res": "0"
    "vehicle":"0"
})

url = "https://booking.snav.it/#/booking/rates/"
res = requests.get(url, params=params)
```

but don't know how to build dynamically the first part after the fixed URL `1040/19-02-2019/1042/19-02-2019`

Comment: You should dig into [Python string formatting](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/). It is one of the basic concepts of the language and you'll benefit a bunch.

Comment: Thank you - surely going to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A URL is really just a string, any of the usual string manipulation techniques would do here. Your component parts don't have any characters in them that would require URL-encoding here either, making the whole process simpler.

If you do have component parts that use characters that are not in the [list of unreserved characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Types_of_URI_characters), then use the [`urllib.parse.quote()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) to convert those characters to URL-safe components.

You could use `str.join()` with `/` to join string parts:

```
outbound_route = '1040'
outbound_date = '19-02-2019'
inbound_route = '1042'
inbound_date = '20-02-2019'

url = "https://booking.snav.it/#/booking/rates"  # no trailing /
final_url = '/'.join([url, outbound_route, outbound_date, inbound_route, inbound_date])
```

or you could use a [formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
url = "https://booking.snav.it/#/booking/rates/"
final_url = f'{url}{outbound_route}/{outbound_date}/{inbound_route}/{inbound_date}'
```

This approach has the advantage that the components don't have to be strings; if `outbound_route` and `inbound_route` are integers, you don't have to explicitly convert them to strings first.

Or, since URL paths work a lot like POSIX filesystem paths, you could use the [`pathlib.PosixPurePath()` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePosixPath) to contruct the path:

```
from pathlib import PosixPurePath

path = PosixPurePath('/booking/rates') / outbound_route / outbound_date / inbound_route / inbound_date
final_url = f"https://booking.snav.it/#{path}"
```

In all cases, you end up with a final URL to use in `requests`:

```
res = requests.get(final_url, params=params)
```

Comment: Thank you - great comprehensive answer.