# How to scrape the same information from the next pages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


url13cases = 'https://hitechfix.com/product-category/cases/apple-cases/iphone- 
cases/iphone-13-6-1-cases/'

r = requests.get(url13cases)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

img = soup.findAll('img',{"class":"attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size- 
woocommerce_thumbnail"})
```

So I am trying to scrape all the pictures from my friends website but the problem is there are a few pages. I just want to know how to edit the url where it goes to the second third and fourth page also. Then I also want to create an array or objects for each link.

The link for page 2 is like this `https://hitechfix.com/product-category/cases/apple-cases/iphone-cases/iphone-13-6-1-cases/page/2/`

Its the same as the last link just the end just the extra `/page/2/` at the end. There are also 2 more pages for 4 pages total how do i get all of them and create objects.

Comment: Could edit your question to one issue specifically? Is it that you want to create an object for a link, or that you want to know how to edit a URL? It's tricky to answer this question without nailing down one specific issue! Maybe write out in pseudocode what you're expecting to do with the HTML?

Comment: I want to get all the info from the next 3 pages and then put them in an object. But the object part i can figure out really just want the next few pages

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54806827/15521392) helps where you could use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) to change the URLs for the different pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use built in function [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) to itrate the pages.

*In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

img_list = []

for i in range(1,5):
    r = requests.get(f'https://hitechfix.com/product-category/cases/apple-cases/iphone-cases/iphone-13-6-1-cases/page/{i}')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    img_list.extend(soup.find_all('img',{"class":"attachment-woocommerce_thumbnail size-woocommerce_thumbnail"}))

img_list
```